# @ replies do not auto-complete (or even show up) on comments

Tags: support, comments

[I cannot seem to get the "auto-complete" pop-up to appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhGUB.png). If I manually write out the entire name when replying, the `@Pedro` bit simply disappears once the comment is posted.

Tested on several questions, and this seems to only be affecting AskUbuntu, and not the rest of StackExchange.

Tested using *FireFox 26.0* and *Ubuntu 13.10*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need a `@` tag if you're responding to the owner of a post. It is discouraged, and thus removed upon submission.

From [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020):

> The first author of the question or answer will always be notified of any new comment. There is no need to use *@name* to notify them. (You may still use it for clarity, if needed; however if only you and the author have been commenting on the post so far, the *@name* will be [automatically removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97098/eeeeek-what-happened-to-my-salutation/97099#97099) from the beginning of the comment, as it adds no value.)

Further explanation [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/97099/232872):

> @lerting the post owner in a comment is not necessary. If comments are only between you and the post-owner, and nobody else is commenting, then an @lert to the post owner at the beginning of a comment will be removed.